# Multiple WinRT CaptureElements

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml

The CaptureElement XAML control is a cool and easy technique to preview the camera on a device in your application's canvas without having to invoke the CameraCaptureUI dialog.

[image]

But... adding more than one doesn't seem to work.

Trying this:

```
var _MediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
await _MediaCapture.InitializeAsync();
Cap1.Source = _MediaCapture;
Cap2.Source = _MediaCapture;
await _MediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync();
```

Results in this on the second 'Source' line:

> {"A method was called at an unexpected time. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000000E)"}

Is there a technique that allows more than one CaptureElement on a single XAML canvas?

Comment: What is happening to SO that a question is /closed/ based on the assumption that the person asking didn't 'try'? How is a question like this even possible without first trying it?

Comment: I asked you if you tried it because it didn't look like you had.  Since you've posted what you tried I voted to reopen.